# Google-Cloud-Speech Adaptation Boost via Swift throwing error

Tags: swift, google-cloud-speech

Successfully using adaptation boost API with Python but not with Swift code. Google API throws error at recognitionConfig.speechContextsArray = arr

Dictionary object in swift is defined differently from Python. So, we tried to pass the dictionary as a string to make it look like a Python dictionary. We tried two approaches. Both are failing as shown below. Can anyone please help?

APPROACH A

```
let dict = [["boost": 15, "phrases": ["fair"]],["phrases": ["fare"],"boost": 2]]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])

    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)!

    print(jsonString)

    let arr: NSMutableArray = [jsonString]
   

  let recognitionConfig = RecognitionConfig()

  recognitionConfig.encoding =  .linear16

  recognitionConfig.sampleRateHertz = Int32(sampleRate)

  recognitionConfig.languageCode = "en-US"

  recognitionConfig.maxAlternatives = 30

  recognitionConfig.enableWordTimeOffsets = true

  recognitionConfig.speechContextsArray = arr
```

APPROACH B
If we go for swift dictionary format which is square brackets at the edges, it fails as well.

```
let dict = [["boost": 15, "phrases": ["fair"]],["phrases": ["fare"],"boost": 2]]
```

APPROACH C

```
let dict = [{"phrases": ["fair"],"boost": 15}, "phrases": ["fare"],"boost":2}]
```

Thanks in advance for help!

[Error Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yc1N.png)